# After Effects Crashes When Exporting To Media Encoder

Tags: after-effects, adobe-media-encoder

When I try to add my work to media encoder queue it used to give me an error about missing plugin.  I found a video online that said to make a symlink from default location to where I have it installed so I did this:

```
mklink /J "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Media Encoder CC 2015" "D:\Program Files\Adobe Media Encoder CC 2015"
```

Now when I go to add to media encoder queue, the media encoder splash screen appears and then it instantly crashes.

Does anyone know what I can do to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

Media encoder takes a real long time to open, I think this is the problem.  If I open media encoder first then after effects second it will export properly.  Just got to wait 5 mins for media encoder to open fully first.